# What is the difference between cpan and cpanm?

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

What is the difference between the `cpan` and `cpanm` commands?

They both seem to install `perl` modules, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 31):

`cpan` the CPAN shell has been shipped with Perl since about 1997.  When you run it the first time it asks a bunch of questions and saves the answers in a config file.  Then you can install a module by running:

```
cpan -i Module::Name
```

The shell provides other commands for searching CPAN and looking inside distribution files.

A project to create a newer, better and more featureful CPAN shell called CPANPLUS (`cpanp` from the command-line) was started by [Jos Boumans](https://metacpan.org/author/KANE), but it was never quite completed to the point where the original vision had been realised.

Meanwhile [MIYAGAWA](https://metacpan.org/author/MIYAGAWA) decided that `cpanp` was trying to do too much and what the world really needed was a simpler shell that did *less* and asked fewer questions (ideally none at all).  He created [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) which provides the `cpanm` command and does exactly what he intended.  You can use it to install a module (and all the module's dependencies) with a command like:

```
cpanm Module::Name
```

The main difference between the two is that if you have Perl you should already have the `cpan` command.  Whereas you won't have `cpanm` unless/until you install it.

Comment: So which one be used to install modules?  Is `cpanm` better because it is newer?

Comment: Use which ever you prefer - either is fine.  I would use `cpan -i App::cpanminus` to install cpanm and then use `cpanm`.  I think it's better because it's simpler (certainly not just because it's newer).

Comment: @CJ7, Neither actually installs anything. They execute the installer included in the distribution to install. As such, the differences are going to be mostly cosmetic. I don't see the point of going out of my way to install `cpanm` just to avoid pressing Enter once the first time `cpan` is run

Comment: Either tool will download the required file(s) from a CPAN mirror, unpack the distribution and then kick off the make/make install process. You use these tools to install modules from CPAN. To say that "neither actually installs anything" is a silly nitpick that almost seems intended to create confusion.

Comment: That's an interesting and informative history, but the OP asked **"What is the difference between cpan and cpanm"**. Your answer came at the end of your post and says *"The main difference between the two is that if you have Perl you should already have the cpan command"*, so they are pretty much *identical* except that you must install `cpanm`. That's not correct and I must -1

Comment: You can also drop the `-i`: `cpan Module::Name`

Answer (score 20):

Most modern Perl users prefer `cpanm` for it's simplicity and mainly, brevity of output.

Using `cpan` can result in hundreds of lines of output as it shows you everything it's doing: downloading, checksum, running installer, parsing, loading, the list goes on. The same applies to every dependency.

`cpanm` on the other hand tells you what it is doing in a more terse and general way, that is: Fetching, Configuring, Building and testing, Done.

So the main difference in usage is that `cpanm` suppresses a lot of (typically) irrelevant information. Sometimes when a module fails, you might want more information. There's a `-v|--verbose` flag that essentially shows you everything `cpan` would.

Also, some modules that require user input may seem to 'hang' when you try to install them. That's because the output that's asking you to type something is suppressed. You can use the `--interactive` (or `--verbose`) flags to work around that.

For a comparison of the output, see slides 35-39 [here](http://www.slideshare.net/genehackdotorg/modern-perl-for-the-unfrozen-paleolithic-perl-programmer-53801333)
or slides 37-41 [here](https://speakerdeck.com/genehack/modern-perl-for-the-unfrozen-paleolithic-perl-programmer?slide=37). (These are from the same presentation. I'm just duplicating the links in case one goes off line.)

Comment: *"Most modern perl users prefer cpanm for it's simplicity and mainly, brevity of output."* That requires a citation and is an unnecessary part of the answer. You are clearly a `cpanm` fan without saying that, and cannot be trusted to give a factual account. *"a more terse and general way"* surely it cannot be both?

Comment: "General" as defined by '_considering or including only the main features or elements of something_'. By only stating the main elements of module installation, the output from `cpanm` is much more terse than that of `cpan`.